# How can I use angular cdk v7 in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am working on a project using angular version 6 in which I have a large list of images so I want to add **`cdk-virtual-scrlling`**, but If I am updating cdk version then it shows error. So how can I use **`cdk-virtual-scrolling`** in angular 6.

Comment: I have a same problem. I want to use it but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can install through `npm i @angular/cdk@7.3.7` But your approach is not good because it may take unstable development and buggy system after your production deployment.

Comment: Than what is its proper solution?

Comment: use the same versions